# Compare input of 2 inputs if it's the same

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm making a form for people the change their passwords and I have a new password and a repeat password field to double check the new password is typed the right way.

I just don't know how to make this, I did try some stuff from the internet but I can't seem to make it work.

These are the fields I have at the moment in my Vue file:

```
<div class="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row mb-2" >
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Current password</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mb-2">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="newPassword">New password</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="newPassword" class="form-control"  type="password" >
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mb-2">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat password </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="repeatPassword" class="form-control" type="password">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click='changePassword'>Confirm</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getProfile(Request $request) {
        $user_late = $request -> user()->getTooLateCount();
        $user_noShow = $request -> user()->getNoShowCount();
        $user_strikes = ($user_late/3)+$user_noShow;

        return view('profile' , [
            'profileName' => $request->user()->name , 
            'profileEmail' => $request->user()->email,
            'strikes'=> $user_strikes
        ]);

    }


}
```

Comment: validation server side?

Comment: Where is the PHP script that will do the checks and amend that database

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I added it to the question, sorry

Comment: @RiggsFolly Added it to the question sorry

Comment: Use the [confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-confirmed) rule

Comment: Also you will need to add a `name="something"` to all the inputs you want to see in the PHP script. `id="something"` is for javascript, `name="something"` is for server side names

Comment: And of course a `<form>` tag, if you dont already have one

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side validation may contain a reference to the 'confirmed' rule of which will enforce that the passwords match.`'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',`

Rename the comparative field to `password_confirmation`.

Don't forget to add the CSRF token if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use Validation [Confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-confirmed)

in your controller add validation

```
$request->validate([
    'password' => 'required|confirmed',
]);
```

in your blade add name to your input

```
<input id="newPassword" class="form-control"  name="password" type="password" >

<input id="newPassword" class="form-control"  name="password_confirmation" type="password" >
```